# How do I solve the following linker error with my OpenGL program in Xcode?

Tags: macos, opengl

I am getting the following errors when I try to compile my C++ OpenGL program in Xcode on Mac OS 10.8...What should I do?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_aglChoosePixelFormat", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_aglCreateContext", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_aglDestroyContext", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_aglDestroyPixelFormat", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_aglSetCurrentContext", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_aglSetFullScreen", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Link against OpenGl. Btw, this is unrelated to Xcode.

Comment: How do I do that?  I already imported the OpenGL framework into XCode.  Do I need to do anything more?  Do I need to add OpenGL to my source Path in XCode?  Thanks again!

Comment: Within your linker settings you will need to [add the OpenGL framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html). Is that what you've done?

Comment: @Advancecoder That should be enough. Tried cleaning the project?

Comment: @H2CO3 I cleaned the project but it didn't still work.

Comment: @Advancecoder Also, have you really added OpenGL to the *linker* (as opposed to the compiler) invocation?

Comment: @Bart I already added OpenGL.framework to my "Link Binary with Libraries" under "Build Phases"...still not a solution...Could there be anything else I am forgetting...

Comment: Hmm, that would have been my idea of the cause of your problem. But if you did that, I'm surprised by the error.

Comment: @H2CO3 How do you add OpenGL to the linker invocation?  Thanks again!

Comment: @Advancecoder Build phases -> link executable with libraries

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, that is already done.  This is really strange... Thanks anyways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using AGL, looking at the reference for [AGL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/agl_opengl/Reference/reference.html), you need to import the framework AGL along with OpenGL.